# Sum of all pairwise row products as a two way matrix

Tags: r, combinations

I'm looking at some high throughput gene data and doing a type of correlation analysis based on Bayesian statistics. One of the things I need to do is to find every pairwise combination of products in the dataset and find the sum of each resultant row.

So for example, for the high throughput dataset matrix `Dataset`

```
(Dataset <- structure(list(`Condition 1` = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), `Condition 2` = c(2L, 1L, 7L, 2L), `Condition 3` = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 5L)), .Names = c("Condition 1", "Condition 2", "Condition 3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene A", "Gene B", "Gene C", "Gene D")))
       Condition 1 Condition 2   Condition 3
Gene A           1           2             4
Gene B           3           1             1
Gene C           2           7             2
Gene D           2           2             5
```

First I want to multiply every possible pair of rows together to get the following matrix called `Comb`:

```
              Condition 1 Condition 2 Condition 3
Gene A Gene A           1           4           9
Gene A Gene B           3           2           4
Gene A Gene C           2          14           8
Gene A Gene D           2           4          20
Gene B Gene B           9           1           1
Gene B Gene C           6           7           2
Gene B Gene D           6           2           5
Gene C Gene C           4          49           4
Gene C Gene D           4          14          10
Gene D Gene D           4           4          25
```

After I want to find the row sums for each product and get the sums in the form of a matrix (which I will call `CombSums`):

```
            Gene A       Gene B      Gene C      Gene D 
Gene A          NA           10          24          26
Gene B          10           NA          15          13
Gene C          24           15          NA          28
Gene D          26           13          28          NA
```

When I tried to do it, the best I could come up with was

```
combs <- combn(seq_len(nrow(Dataset)), 2)
Comb <- Dataset[combs[1,], ] * Dataset[combs[2,], ]
rownames(Comb) <- apply(combn(rownames(Comb), 2), 2, paste, collapse = " ")
CombSums <- rowSums(Comb)
```

Which would gives me the sums as a list, such as below:

```
                    [1,]
Gene A Gene B       10
Gene A Gene C       24 
Gene A Gene D       26 
Gene B Gene C       15
Gene B Gene D       13
Gene C Gene D       28
```

Unfortunately, I want it as a two-way matrix and not a list so this doesn't quite work, so if anyone could suggest a way to get the sums as a matrix, that would be a great help.

Comment: I believe the (1, 2) and (2, 1) values should be 9 (3+2+4), not 10.

Comment: In the `Comb` matrix (1,3) should possibly be 16 not 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If speed is an important factor (e.g. if you're processing a huge matrix), you might find an Rcpp implementation helpful. This only fills the upper triangular portion of the matrix.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
 "NumericMatrix josilberRcpp(NumericMatrix x) {
   const int nr = x.nrow();
   const int nc = x.ncol();
   NumericMatrix y(nr, nr);
   for (int col=0; col < nc; ++col) {
    for (int i=0; i < nr; ++i) {
      for (int j=i; j < nr; ++j) {
        y(i, j) += x(i, col) * x(j, col);
      }
    }
   }
   return y;
}")
josilberRcpp(as.matrix(Dataset))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   21    9   24   26
# [2,]    0   11   15   13
# [3,]    0    0   57   28
# [4,]    0    0    0   33
```

Benchmarking is provided in my other answer. Note that the benchmarking does not include the compile time using `cppFunction`, which can be quite significant. Therefore this implementation is probably only useful for very large inputs or when you need to use this function many times.

Comment: Judging by the OP's output, you can also skip the diagonal, `for(int j = i+1...` (or something like that)

Comment: So would the other response by josilber be faster for smaller datasets, but it would be this post that is faster for large datasets? (I'm not familiar with the Rcpp package, so I apologize if this seems like a trivial question) But I'll be looking at high throughput sequencing data, so that would likely be 10 000+ genes across many conditions (20 - 30 or even more). I would assume that such a dataset would be large enough that the method in this post would be faster? Also, how would I add back in the row and column names (e.g. Gene A, Gene B, etc.) to the final matrix?

Comment: @NelLau To add names, you can use `res <- josilberRcpp(x); dimnames(res) <- list(rownames(x),rownames(x))` or wrap those two steps inside another function. After that, you can use names to subset, like `res["Gene A","Gene B"]`. I suspect that, working with genetic data, you'll want to go with an Rcpp approach, yeah. However, I'd suggest just trying both this and the `josilber2` function, as you are best positioned to find out which is better for your application.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by computing the pairwise products for each column in your original data frame with `lapply` and `outer`, and then you can add all those pairwise products together with `Reduce` and `+`.

```
Reduce("+", lapply(dat, function(x) outer(x, x)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   21    9   24   26
# [2,]    9   11   15   13
# [3,]   24   15   57   28
# [4,]   26   13   28   33
```

A variation on that theme that is less memory intensive (because it doesn't need to store each column's matrix at the same time) but more typing would be:

```
ret <- outer(dat[,1], dat[,1])
for (i in 2:ncol(dat)) ret <- ret + outer(dat[,i], dat[,i])
ret
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   21    9   24   26
# [2,]    9   11   15   13
# [3,]   24   15   57   28
# [4,]   26   13   28   33
```

Here's a benchmark of the approaches proposed so far on a 100 x 100 data frame:

```
# Larger dataset
set.seed(144)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow=100))

josilber <- function(dat) Reduce("+", lapply(dat, function(x) outer(x, x)))
josilber2 <- function(dat) {
  ret <- outer(dat[,1], dat[,1])
  for (i in 2:ncol(dat)) ret <- ret + outer(dat[,i], dat[,i])
  ret
}
frank <- function(DF) {
  mat   <- as.matrix(DF)
  pairs <- combn(1:nrow(DF),2)
  vals  <- rowSums(mat[pairs[1,],]*mat[pairs[2,],])
  res   <- matrix(,nrow(DF),nrow(DF),dimnames=list(rownames(DF),rownames(DF)))
  res[lower.tri(res)] <- vals
  res
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(josilber(dat), josilber2(dat), josilberRcpp(as.matrix(dat)), frank(dat))
# Unit: microseconds
#                          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#                 josilber(dat)  6867.499 45437.277 45506.731 46372.576 47549.834 85494.063   100
#                josilber2(dat)  6831.692  7982.539 10245.459  9109.023 10883.965 50612.600   100
#  josilberRcpp(as.matrix(dat))   989.592  1112.316  1290.617  1204.388  1483.638  2384.348   100
#                    frank(dat) 13043.912 53369.804 52488.997 53921.402 54855.583 62566.730   100
```

Comment: Interesting. I would've guessed that outer would be slower (since it has to do more than twice as many calculations).

Comment: @Frank true, but no need to compute intermediate objects `pairs`, `DF[pairs[1,],]` or `DF[pairs[2,],]`.

Comment: I guess mine is considerably less memory intensive...? The result of that `lapply` is quite immense and caused my computer to hang when I checked `n=500; dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n^2), nrow=n))`.  By the way, I just changed my method to convert to matrix, so it's not quite so bad for your benchmark. It's too bad there's not some `Reduce` that would only compute the elements of the list sequentially (so you only need two in memory at a time)...a loop could do that, I guess.

Comment: Hm, now that I think of it, that case should only occupy 1 GB (= 500 matrices with dimensions 500x500, storing numerics, which take 8 bytes each). Maybe R is somehow poorly optimized to handle that case, though.

Comment: @Frank good point -- I was really optimizing for code length and not speed in the original answer, but that for loop is quite a bit quicker (I've added it to the benchmark). I suppose it's not too much more typing, either!

Comment: Cool, I wasn't expecting that kind of speedup! Yeah, the direction of further improvement that I can think of from here, Rcpp, would take much longer code.

Comment: @Frank added another answer with Rcpp -- it's not terribly long, and gets a decent speedup (another 7.5x).

Answer (score 4):

Using `combn`, you can avoid doing redundant calculations:

```
mat   <- as.matrix(DF)

pairs <- combn(1:nrow(DF),2)

vals  <- rowSums(mat[pairs[1,],]*mat[pairs[2,],])
res   <- matrix(,nrow(DF),nrow(DF),dimnames=list(rownames(DF),rownames(DF)))
res[lower.tri(res)] <- vals

#       GeneA GeneB GeneC GeneD
# GeneA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# GeneB     9    NA    NA    NA
# GeneC    24    15    NA    NA
# GeneD    26    13    28    NA
```

Your `Comb` matrix is the intermediate result `mat[pairs[1,],]*mat[pairs[2,],]`.

---

The entire calculation can be done inside `combn`, alternately:

```
vals <- combn(rownames(DF),2,FUN=function(x)sum(apply(DF[x,],2,prod)))
```

As @josilber pointed out in a comment below, this is incredibly slow, however.

---

**Data:**

```
DF <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="Condition1 Condition2   Condition3
GeneA           1           2             4
GeneB           3           1             1
GeneC           2           7             2
GeneD           2           2             5")
```

Comment: The second one (providing a function to `combn`) is quite slow (8 seconds for my 100 x 100 example).

Comment: I think the issue with the second one is that it's not well vectorized (it performs a `*` and `sum` call for each pair of genes). Meanwhile your first one performs a single multiplication and a single call to `rowSums`.